# Service anniversaries today with SharePoint using calculated fields and filters

Tags: date, sharepoint, filter

I need to create a view that show employees that have their Service anniversary today.

I am familiar with the problems with using [Today] in calculated fields but still thought that this was a straight forward thing to do.

I have a list with a [Hire Date] field.
In that list I have created a calculated field [Hire Date - mmdd] with the formula `=TEXT([Hire Date],"mmdd")`.

With this someone hired 15 years ago today will for instance get the value 1115

This works fine. So far so good.

Next step is of course to create a view in order to list employees with Service Anniversary today - knowing that [Today] is allowed in filters.

I create a view selecting all employees with [Hire Date - mmdd] is equal to TEXT([Today],"mmdd")

But it does not work !!!

Why does this not work when [Today] is otherwise working fine in filters.

BTW: This is SharePoint 2007

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't work because you can't put anything other than very basic calculations in filters.

The filter is looking for records that have

[Hire Date - mmdd] = "TEXT[Today],'mmdd'"

without doing the text calculation turning TODAY[xxxxx] into "1115"

Comment: I should think that TEXT([Today],"mmdd") is a fairly basic calculation to have in a filter.
Anyone know of reference material available that describe what kind of calculations are allowed (and what kind of calculations are NOT allowed) in filters?

Comment: You might think that, I couldn't possibly comment ;) AFAIK the only thing that you can have in the filter is [Field]+/-(VALUE)